# Inconsistent class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I've read about class constructor [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) and a question then arises as to why does the following hierachy is incorrect:

```
public class Test extends Subclass.Inner{ //compile-time error 
                           //The hierarchy of the type Test is inconsistent
    public Test() {
        super();
    }
}


public class Subclass extends Test{
    public class Inner{
    }
}
```

Formally

> If a superclass constructor invocation statement is unqualified, and
>   if S is an inner member class, then it is a compile-time error if S is
>   not a member of a lexically enclosing class of C by declaration or
>   ***inheritance***.

I thought the example completely satisfies the rule I cited. In the case `SubClass` is lexically inclosing class for `Test` by inheritance. Why doesn't the code work fine? Could you provide an appropriate example reflecting that?

Answer (score 2):

Inner instance classes (non-static) are actually transformed like so:

```
public class Subclass extends Test {
    public class Inner {
    }
}
```

becomes something like this:

```
public class Subclass extends Test {

}

public class Inner {
    Subclass parent;
    public Inner(Subclass parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The following is valid:

```
public class Container extends Subclass {
    public class Test extends Subclass.Inner {
        public Test() {
            super();
        }
    }
}

public class Subclass {
    public class Inner {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An instance of an inner class must have an enclosing instance, which gets initialized before the inner class instance. On the other hand, a super class constructor is always executed before a sub-class constructor. Therefore, creating an instance of `SubClass` requires calling first the constructor of `Test`, which requires calling first the constructor of `SubClass.Inner`, but `SubClass.Inner` cannot be initialized before its containing instance.

I believe that in order to satisfy the condition you quoted, the super class Inner must be enclosed by a super class of Test. In your case it is enclosed by a sub-class of Test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clause you are missing ([8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)):

> A class C *directly* depends on a type T if T is mentioned in the `extends` or `implements` clause of C either as a superclass or superinterface, **or as a qualifier of a superclass or superinterface name**.
>
> A class C *depends* on a reference type T if any of the following conditions hold:
>
> - **C directly depends on a class D that depends on T (using this definition recursively).**
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a class depends on itself.**

It is a compile-time error because the *declaration of a superclass* of `Subclass` contains `Subclass` as a *qualifier of a superclass name*.

That is besides the extremely weird circular definition you have going here. `Test` would be an outer scope of itself.

This doesn't compile either, though it's not as puzzling as the inner class:

```
class Test implements Test.ITest {
    interface ITest {}
}
```

Netbeans gives me a more straightforward error that there is 'cyclic inheritance'. A class declaration is not allowed to reference itself in this manner.